# Select and return multiple array elements? etc. arrayName.get(1 through 3)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to format a string, the number of spaces between each word needs to change on a per string basis. I have completed the code that calculated the required number of blank spaces. I made an array with several " " elements that I'm using to change the number of spaces between each word. How do I print X through Y elements in my array?

```
blankarrayList.get(1-2) // just prints the item in position -1
blankarrayList.get(1,2) // just prints items one and two, this works but 
                        // doesnt allow me to easily change the number printed (that i know of)


public static String format(List<String> myWords) {
    System.out.println(myWords.get(0) + blankarrayList.get(/*array positions 1 through 3*/) 
                     + myWords.get(1) + blankarrayList.get(/*array positions 1 through 3*/)
                     + myWords.get(2) + blankarrayList.get(/*array positions 1 through 3*/)
                     + my words.get(3));

    return myWords.get(0);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop?

Comment: *"just prints the item in position -1"* - Are you sure about this? I think an exception will be thrown if you try to access a negative index, possibly a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What you're trying to do seems like it could be solved with `String.format(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blankarrayList.get(/*array positions 1 through 3*/)

blankarrayList.subList(1, 3); // This gives a sub-list which specified index
```

So you can combine all the elements in your new sub-list like below

```
System.out.println(myWords.get(0) + StringUtils.join(blankarrayList.subList(1, 3), "") 
                 + myWords.get(1) + StringUtils.join(blankarrayList.subList(1, 3), "")
                 + myWords.get(2) + StringUtils.join(blankarrayList.subList(1, 3), "")
                 + my words.get(3));
```

Also you can write everything like below:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(myWords, blankarrayList.subList(1, 3)));
```